# ! Illegal parameter number in definition of \NewValue

Tags: biblatex, errors

Everything works fine until I added the following URL reference to my `references.bib` file. The URL reference is output but I am getting the error

> Illegal parameter number in definition of `\NewValue`.

in addition.

```
@misc{jdk,
  author = {Oracle},
  title = {Platform, Standard Edition 7
Development Kit},
  howpublished = {\url{http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/jdk-7-readme-429198.html#contents}},
  note = {Accessed: 2015}
}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
%\bibliography{references} 
%\addbibresource{<database>.<extension>}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\begin{document}
Hallo world\cite{einstein} I do not if it \cite{jdk} Tree Tree bla bla will work test \nocite{Doe:2009:Online}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Without a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) it's impossible to say anything.

Comment: I have deleted the part from my refernces.bib and everything works again if I add it then I am getting the error! I think it is up to the jdk reference

Comment: That's clear; but without a minimal example it's hard to tell what's happening.

Comment: I an writing a thesis ...it works if I put  backslash behind the number sign # in the url but the problem is, that the url is being displayed with the backslash in the pdf file.

Comment: So I added one. Please see my updated question.

Comment: Have you added `\usepackage{url}`?

Comment: No! I added it right now  but I am still getting the error. As i said if I but backslash behinde the number sign, then it works smoothy

Comment: Following up on @HarishKumar's suggestion: after adding the instruction `\usepackage{url}`, did you rerun latex, bibtex, and latex twice more?

Comment: @HarishKumar `biblatex` already loads `url`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use the `url` and `urldate`, rather than `howpublished` and `note`:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{jdk,
  author = {Oracle},
  title = {Platform, Standard Edition 7 Development Kit},
  url = {http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/jdk-7-readme-429198.html#contents},
  urldate = {2015},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  urlseen={Accessed:}% %%% not `visited on'
}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

Hello world\cite{einstein} I do not if it \cite{jdk} will work test
\nocite{Doe:2009:Online}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Note that the `filecontents*` environment is just to make the example self contained and you can use your file (after modifying it as suggested).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone comes here for the same reason I did, this was because I had the special character `#` in the title of a paper I was citing. (In particular, http://people.csail.mit.edu/shaih/pubs/01perm.pdf .) The error message was pretty inscrutable, gave me the the wrong line numbers, only showed up on the *second* compilation when I introduced it, and was accompanied by other messages like

```
illegal parameter number in definition of \abs@field@title
illegal parameter number in definition of \abs@field@journal
```

I figure I'll throw those lines in here for Googleability. In my case, I had to change

```
title="Zero-one permanent is #P-complete, a simpler proof"
```

to

```
title="Zero-one permanent is \#P-complete, a simpler proof"
```

and re-compile.